# namespace php и динамическое создание объектов

Tags: php, mvc, namespace

Есть класс *Route*, который динамически создает объекты класса *Controller*, исходя из адресной строки ([тот самый MVC-шаблон из habr'a](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/)).

В общем, понадобилось мне использовать *namespace*'ы в своем приложении. Но, встал вопрос, как динамически создавать объекты в классе *Route*?

Класс **Route**:

```
<?php

use core\controllers as cc;

class Route
{
static function start()
{

    //контроллер и действие по умолчанию
    $controller_name = 'Main';
    $action_name = 'index';

    //разбиваем uri на страницы
    $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    //получаем имя контроллера, начинаем с первого, т.к. 0й элемент - dns-адрес хоста
    if (!empty($routes[1])) {
        $controller_name = $routes[1];
    }

    //получаем имя экшена
    if (!empty($routes[2])) {
        $action_name = $routes[2];
    }

    //добавляем префиксы
    $model_name = 'Model_' . $controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller_' . $controller_name;
    $action_name = 'Action_' . $action_name;

    //подцепляем файл с классом модели (файла может и не быть)

    $model_file = strtolower($model_name) . '.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/" . $model_file;
    if (file_exists($model_path)) {
        include "application/models/" . $model_file;
    }

    //подцепляем файл с классом контроллера

    $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name) . '.php';
    $controller_path = "application/controllers/" . $controller_file;
    if (file_exists($controller_path)) {
        include "application/controllers/" . $controller_file;
    } else {
        /*
              правильно было бы кинуть здесь исключение,
              но для упрощения сразу сделаем редирект на страницу 404
              */
        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

    //создаем контроллер
    $controller = new $controller_name;
    $action = $action_name;
    if ($controller_name == "Controller_Product") {
        if ($action != 'Action_index') {
            $action = "Action_product";
        }
    }

    if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        //вызываем действие контроллера
        $controller->$action();
    } else {
        // здесь также разумнее было бы кинуть исключение
        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

    if ($controller_name == "Admin") {
        $controller->$action();
    }


}

static function ErrorPage404()
{
    $host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    header('Location:' . $host . '404');
}
}
```

Нужно решение, как создать объекты в этом коде, используя namespace?

Пробовал добавлять *alias* namespace'a  к `$controller = new $controller_name;`, но, ясное дело это не увенчалось успехом.

И ничего, к сожалению, не приходит в голову.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В строке, содержащую имя класса, необходимо указать полное имя класса вместе с пространством имён. Директивы `use` при этом тоже не используются.

```
$controller_class_name = 'core\\controllers\\' . $controller_name;
$controller = new $controller_class_name;
```

Comment: Да, действительно! Спасибо большое!